# How do I get actual config in puppeteer?

Tags: puppeteer

I want to conditionally execute some code based on the `headless` config attribute in puppeteer (passed in the `.launch` function).

e.g. : when I use the `.type` function, if it is running with `headless: true`, I don't want any `delay`. Else, add some `{ delay: 200 }`.

How can I retrieve the `headless` value from the config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the latest puppeteer version to date (1.7.0), this is how I retrieved the config :

```js
const client = await page.target().createCDPSession();
const response = await client.send('Browser.getBrowserCommandLine');
page.headless = response.arguments.includes('--headless');
```

See [this github issue](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/3095) for more information

Answer (score 0):

**Edit** *(thanks to @AndreyLushnikov comment)*

You can figure out if puppeteer runs (non-)headless at runtime by checking [browser.process()](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v1.7.0&show=api-browserprocess) `spawnargs` for `--headless` switch with which Chromium were (or not) launched:

```
const headless = browser.process().spawnargs.includes("--headless") ? true : false;
console.log("Headless? " + headless);
```

Comment: Thing is I use different files for the setup and the tests, I might need to go through global variables for this to work. I'll wait some more time and accept your answer if there's no more straight way to get it - e.g. ``puppetter.getConfig`` or smthg like that

Comment: there's also [browser.process()](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v1.7.0&show=api-browserprocess), so using private API is not necessary.

Comment: I use the ``connect`` method, thus ``.process()`` returns null